# Javascript - modify CSS on HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, css, html

The HTML tag on this page I'm working on is in a class that is giving it a top `padding` of `28px`. I need this to go away temporarily when a button is clicked, but it doesn't appear that I can change the styling of the HTML tag itself.

Will I need to use `position: relative;` on the body tag or something similar? Is there really a way to assign CSS to the HTML tag that I don't know about?

@ Comments:

Sorry, I'm in a bit of a rush here. It's something to the effect of this:

```
<html class='pad_my_top'>
<head>

<style type='text/css'>
    .pad_my_top{
        padding-top: 28px;
    }

    body{
        background: #000000;
    }
</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    function its_gone(){
        // Something here to remove padding.
        alert("It's gone. Hurray!");
        // Something to put it back.
    }
</script>

</html>
<body>

<button onClick='its_gone()'>Click me to get rid of the top padding</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I really want it gone so I can print the page with Javascript, but I'd rather not use any 3rd party code because this is for a plugin for Wordpress and I don't want a billion dependencies. I only need to hide/re-display 3 divs and (re)change 2 styles.

Comment: can you share code? preferably fiddle, but atleast paste the html code you need help with

Comment: If you really need to get rid of that padding and don't have control over it, use `html { padding-top: 0 !important; }`. Or in your case, create a class that you can add to the `html` that has `padding-top: 0 !important;` in it...then you can remove it when done with the button being clicked

Comment: Do you want the class to go away, or just the padding?

Comment: It doesn't matter to me so long as it's put back exactly the way it was when the function is complete.

Comment: Are you sure you want to put the class on the `html` tag and not on the body? Guess it doesn't matter, it just seems unusual. Also it's slightly easier to access the body from javascript - `document.body` compared to `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]`

Comment: Yeah. This is Wordpress, so I don't have control over the stupid things like that. Trust me, if I could change it, I would.

Comment: @Stuart Why do you have to use that? Just use `document.documentElement`...

Comment: @user1813212 I added an answer that uses classes - the cleaner way to go. You don't have to like it or accept it or anything (I know you already got your "answer"), I just wanted to provide a different solution

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use this to remove the top padding:

```
document.documentElement.style.paddingTop = "0";
```

and this to set it back:

```
document.documentElement.style.paddingTop = "28px";
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason to use `getElementsByTagName` and whatnot...just use `document.documentElement`. Also, it's better to use a class and toggle that instead of directly setting the style attribute. What if you change the `28px` to `20px` in your CSS? Then you have to change it somewhere else. Since you are *sure* you want the `top-padding` to be `0`, then add a class that sets that. When done, remove that class. Like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .no-top-padding {
        padding: 0 !important;
    }
</style>

document.documentElement.className += " no-top-padding";
```

And to "add" the padding back (by effectively removing the class):

```
var old_class = document.documentElement.className;
document.documentElement.className = old_class.replace(/(?:^|\s)no-top-padding(?!\S)/g, "");
```

Although it could be done a lot cleaner with the DOM API `classList`. The regex is just a safer way for making sure the `className` property is modified correctly to remove the "no-top-padding" class.

Comment: Awesome. I was hoping that there's be something a bit cleaner than getElementsByTagName, which is the whole reason I asked this question really.