# Switch the HTML's CSS on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a website in which there are two ways to scroll

1. Scroll Snapping
2. Traditional

Current code

```
html,body{
    margin: 0;
    scroll-snap-type:y mandatory ;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

But I want to make button which can turn off scroll snapping.

I know I can edit the CSS of the body, but how to edit the CSS of the HTML?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript - modify CSS on HTML tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809178/javascript-modify-css-on-html-tag)

Comment: instead of editing the CSS you should add/remove/toggle a class that applies the changes

Comment: toggle a class....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add button with (JavaScript) onclick value:

```
document.documentElement.style.scrollSnapType = 'none'
```

```css
html,body{

 margin: 0;
 
scroll-snap-type:y mandatory ;
flex-direction: column;}


div{
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
button{
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="document.documentElement.style.scrollSnapType = 'none';">disable scroll-snap-type</button>
<div style="background:#844"></div>
<div style="background:#484"></div>
<div style="background:#448"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a button in your HTML to toggle scroll snapping:

```
<button id="toggleScrollSnapping">Toggle Scroll Snapping</button>
```

Add an event listener to the button to toggle the scroll snapping behavior:

```
const toggleButton = document.getElementById('toggleScrollSnapping');
const htmlElement = document.documentElement;

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    htmlElement.classList.toggle('scroll-snapping-disabled');
});
```

Define your CSS rules to enable or disable scroll snapping based on the class applied to the  element:

```
html {
    /* ... other CSS rules ... */
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.scroll-snapping-enabled {
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.scroll-snapping-disabled {
    scroll-snap-type: none;
}
```

Apply the CSS class to the  element when the button is clicked:

```
toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    htmlElement.classList.toggle('scroll-snapping-disabled');
    htmlElement.classList.toggle('scroll-snapping-enabled');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,body{

 margin: 0;
 
scroll-snap-type:y mandatory ;
flex-direction: column;}


div{
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
button{
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="document.documentElement.style.scrollSnapType = 'none';">disable scroll-snap-type</button>
<div style="background:#951"></div>
<div style="background:#100"></div>
<div style="background:#890"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a checkbox with a has selector to enable and disable a css rule based on the checkbox state.

```css
.slider {
    display: flex;
}

body:has(#snap:checked) .slider
{
    -ms-scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

section {
    min-width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="snap" /><label for="snap">Snap It</label>
<div class="slider">
    <section>
        <h1>Section One</h1>
    </section>
    <section >
        <h1>Section Two</h1>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h1>Section Three</h1>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h1>Section Four</h1>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h1>Section Five</h1>
    </section>
</div>
```